# Replacing && and || with a switch statement

Tags: c#

Can I use `&` , `||` operator using `switch` statement?

Like

```
if(a==b & b==c)
```

or

```
if(a==b || b==c)
```

using `switch` statement instead of `if`?

Comment: Why would you ever want to?

Comment: I presume you mean `&&` instead of the bitwise `&`?

Answer (score 1):

The only real options is to create a bitfield and then have a switch for every combination, but for any significant number of flags this is unworkable.  If the issue is very deeply nested conditionals you should look at a state machine or reworking your architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `switch` statements only allow a single condition.

Comment: Even worse, they allow only a singular const condition.

Answer (score 0):

Switches are for comparing one value against a series of other values. You've got 7 comparisons there, which makes it unsuitable for a case.

Answer (score 0):

You can't: each switch label must be a constant value.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

`&` is not possible.

If you want to compare one variable to multiple values, that's possible. So some statement like `if (a=='a' || a=='b')` can be expressed this way:

```
switch( b )
{
    case 'a':
    case 'b':
        do_something();
        break;

[...]

    default:
        do_something_else_if_you_want_to();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Hint: express your homework in terms of simple if statements, then express an if using switch, since `if (test) something(); else otherthing();` is equivalent to `switch (test) { case 0: otherthing(); break; default: something(); break;}` and use composition for the complex case.